# Query works in some databases but not others. Appears to be a query parsing issue dealing with nested functions. Any idea why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL Server 2008 query that works for all of my databases (50+) except for one. This query should only be relying on system level features so it should run on any SQL Server database. All of my databases are on a single server so it isn't a server issue but a single database instance issue.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS istats
WHERE avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 20
```

I get the following error in the offending database.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.

The following two queries work fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(72, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS istats           
WHERE avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 20


select DB_ID()
```

So, it appears to be an issue that SQL Server is having when parsing out the query just in this one particular database. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your [compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) is the same across all databases. I bet the ones where this syntax is not working are set to something less than 100. You can check a database's compatibility level by the following query:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = x;
```

That said, these databases may be in a lower compat level by choice, and it might not be the best idea to just upgrade them. To work around the issue, you can also try:

```
DECLARE @DB INT = DB_ID();
SELECT * FROM sys.function...(@DB, ...);
```

Comment: Way to go @Aaron Bertrand, you beat me again.  +1 anyway.

Comment: No worries, I returned the favor.

Answer (score 2):

Check the compatibility level on the problem database.  I just tried your query on a database after setting compatibility level to SQL Server 2000 with the following.

```
ALTER DATABASE Junk
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 80
```

I got the same error.